# Parse text in attribute

Tags: c#, find, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to parse text from an attribute: `src="/captcha?58428805"`.
I need the text `/captcha?58428805`, every time it's different.
How can I parse it?

**Example element:**

```
<img style="margin: 0;height:40px;width:115px;" 
     width="115" height="40"
     id="captcha" class="captcha" src="/captcha?58428805" 
     alt="Verification code with letters and numbers "/>
```

Comment: You could read about [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SubString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) . You could also use a Regular Expression

Answer (score 0):

There are various kinds of methods, as @Pikoh said in comments, and I wrote the **Regex** version for you. The regex string may change a little according how variant your html strings are.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "your html string";
        string strReg = @"<img style=.+?src=""(.+?)""";
        Regex reg = new Regex(strReg,
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string youneed = reg.Match(input).Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(youneed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lei Yang's answer might be correct, it will fail if `src=SRC_VALUE` comes right after `<image..` like this: `<img src="/captcha?58428805" ...SOME_OTHER ATTR..>`

This regex might help:

```
string toTest = @"<img style=""margin: 0;height:40px;width:115px;"" width=""115"" height=""40"" id=""captcha"" class=""captcha"" src=""/captcha?58428805"" alt="" Verification code with letters and numbers ""/>";
var regex = new Regex(@"<img.{0,}src=""(.+?)""");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(toTest).Groups[1].Value);
```

Explanation for `<img.{0,}src="(.+?)"` (note that quotes are escaped in the above code):

> `<img` - string should contain `<img`
>
> `.{0,}` - matches between zero to infinite occurences of any character except line terminators after the `<img`
>
> `src="` - matches the `src="` part after `<img`
>
> `(.+?)"` - `.` means any character except line terminators, (`+`) occuring 1 or unlimited times, (`?`) [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), and  should end in `"`.

This regex however will only return the last `src` value even if your `toTest` string contains multiple `<img>` tags. So, you need to `Split` your string per `<img>` tag then apply the regex above:

```
string toTest = @"<img style=""margin: 0;height:40px;width:115px;"" width=""115"" height=""40"" id=""captcha"" class=""captcha"" src=""/captcha?58428805"" alt="" Verification code with letters and numbers ""/><img style=""margin: 0;height:40px;width:115px;"" width=""115"" height=""40"" id=""captcha"" class=""captcha"" src=""/captssscha?5842sss8805"" alt="" Verification code with letters and numbers ""/>";
var imgArr = Regex.Split(toTest, @"(<img[\s\S]+?\/>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray(); //split the html string by <image> tag
var srcRegex = new Regex(@"<img.{0,}src=""(.+?)""",RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach(string imgTag in imgArr) {
    Console.WriteLine(srcRegex.Match(imgTag).Groups[1].Value);
}
```